# IOS/Objective-C: Shared Instance Method with argument

Tags: ios, lazy-loading

Hi I have a class that I am lazyloading as a sharedInstance. I would like to be able to call a method in the class that requries an input variable but the following syntax is not working.  It says there is no such property but I copied the property from the interface.

Here is code that is not working

```
int myPoints = 200;
//myStatusLevel is a method in ManagePoints that takes mypoints as an input
// its signature is (int)myStatusLevel: (int) points;
//the following line gives error prperty myStatusLevel not found
int myStatusLevel =[ManagePoints sharedInstance].myStatusLevel:myPoints;
```

Can this be done and, if so, what is the proper syntax?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a method in ManagePoints with the following signature:

`-(int)myStatusLevel:(int)points;`

then you should be able call that function and pass an argument.

You need to use square brackets:

`int myStatusLevel = [[ManagePoints sharedInstance] myStatusLevel:myPoints];`